# Time Series before initial value

Tags: time-series

If a time series starts at time index 1 , does it imply for all 
$t < 1$ $y_t= 0$ ?

Comment: "Starts" at index 1 means exactly that: there is nothing defined for earlier indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it means that the time series did not exist before time t=1 or that the researcher chooses not to include observations before that time. For some time series models the likelihood function depends on observations before t=1. For example in an AR(2) model one needs y(-1) and y(0) to predict y(1). In the time series literature, "exact maximum likelihood" estimators deal with the unavailability of data before t=1. Sometimes approximate likelihood estimators that assume y(t) = 0 or e(t) = 0 for t < 1 are used, when the sample size is large. Here e(t) stands for the innovation at time t.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we suppose that for all $t<0$, $y_t = \mathbb{E}[y_t]$. For exemple, in the case of a AR(1) model, $y_t=\alpha+\beta y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t\quad \epsilon_t\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, you'll have $y_t=\tfrac{\alpha}{1-\beta}\, \text{ if} t<0$.